# Invoke execvp from linux driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, execvp

Currently, i want to call execvp from kernel side.
My program is programmed to go to halt mode.
So i have tried to setup below code:

```
char   *argv[] = { "/sbin/halt", "-f", NULL };
char * envp[] = {
            "SHELL=/bin/sh",
            "HOME=/",        
            "PATH=.:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin",
            "PWD=/",
             NULL };
rc = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
```

It seems that the code can execute halt command well.
But it does not meet the requirement about the electric signal.
I have checked, when i call execvp from the user space:

```
execvp ("halt", argv);
```

It worked well as expected.

I know that execvp will replace the current running programming by  the new one specified in passing argument. When i use call_usermodehelper, that does not happen, i think it could be the difference.
Anyone know how can i solved this problem? How to make execvp work in driver similar to user space.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355951/issue-running-process-from-a-linux-kernel-module) on Unix and Linux StackExchange.

Comment: @Gaurav i have looked at this link. But it is different from my problem. 
In my case, the halt command can be executed well when i use call_usermodehelper. But the result seems different from calling execvp ("halt", argv) in user application. By using execvp ("halt", argv), the CPU signal can be pull down to 0V.
Anyway, what are the point you want to propose to modify in my program from your link?